# Unable to retrieve values from eBay API response using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ebay-api

I am trying to build a very simple tool for use at my work. I work for eBay and currently the tools available are cumbersome for the task. We are asked to compare text and images to check that sellers aren't stealing each others content. I am using the eBay Trading API and the sample HTML/CSS/Javascript code given when the developer account was created. Ultimately what I hope to achieve is a simple page that displays two items' photo and description next to each other. However, right now I am simply trying to edit the sample code given to display the start date of the auction.

My question is this: I am trying add a variable who's value is determined by a response from the API. some of these are provided in the sample however, when I add my own `var starttime = items.listingInfo.startTime` to the function and add the variable to the HTML table none of the data displays including those that displayed prior to my addition. Unfortunately I don't have more than a rudimentary understanding of javascript and so am unsure if I am even properly phrasing this question, let alone getting the syntax of my addition correct. What am I doing wrong?

below is the sample text with my addition of one declared variable (`starttime`) and one addition to the HTML table

```
<html>
<head>
<title>eBay Search Results</title>
<style type="text/css">body { font-family: arial,sans-serif;} </style>
</head> 
<body>
<h1>eBay Search Results</h1>
<div id="results"></div>

<script>
function _cb_findItemsByKeywords(root)
{
  var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
  var html = [];
  html.push('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"><tbody>');

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)  
  {
    var item     = items[i];
    var title    = item.title;
        var viewitem = item.viewItemURL;
    var starttime = items.listingInfo.startTime;

    if (null != title && null != viewitem)
    {
      html.push('<tr><td>' + '<img src="' + pic + '" border="0">' + '</td>' + 
        '<td><a href="' + viewitem + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a>' + starttime + '</td></tr>');
    }
  }
  html.push('</tbody></table>');
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html.join("");
}
</script>

<!--
Use the value of your appid for the appid parameter below.
-->
<script src=http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=iphone%203g&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3>
</script>
</body>
</html>"
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response! I will do that! I am pretty sure they are there though. If you wouldn't mind looking at what I'm looking at on this page it actually shows the JSON object in xml next to the other code. If I'm completely missing something here then I apologize.

this is the page I am viewing, not sure if you need an eBay Developer account to view it though (they're free if that helps?).

 http://developer.ebay.com/quickstartguide/sample/js/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you believe `listingInfo` is an property of individual items, and that it is an object that has the property `startTime`, then the proper syntax is:

```
var item     = items[i];
var title    = item.title;
var viewitem = item.viewItemURL;
var starttime = item.listingInfo.startTime;
```

You are currently referencing `items` which is the array of items, not an individual item.

### Update

I looked into this via the [URL](http://developer.ebay.com/quickstartguide/sample/js/default.aspx) you put in the comments. The solution to this particular problem is this:

```
var starttime = item.listingInfo[0].startTime;
```

I hope that helps. Please review the FAQ; Imho this question falls outside the [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) of this site (the question is really quite narrow, and not likely to help anyone else). I recommend [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) as a source for learning more about JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am in desparate need of someone to ask my super basic questions to. Would you mind if I sent a few more questions your way?

Comment: Thank you! you'be been a great help and I appreciate it a lot! This edit of the sample code was my first hands-on attempt to understand javascript. I read through the scope link you included above and agree that my question was too narrow to have warranted an answer and for this I again thank you for your courtesy! I've broadened my question to more accurately describe what I'm asking and hoping to achieve. It has been reposted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535889/how-to-properly-call-the-ebay-trading-api-and-display-the-results