# How to properly call the eBay Trading API and display the results

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ebay-api

I am attempting to build a tool for use at my work that compares some very simple data. All of the data is available through the eBay trading API via the GetItem call. In the Trading API guide from the eBay Developer website the sample input and output code to make the GetItem call is shown in XML. However I'm still confused on how to write something in HTML/Javascript that makes the call and then displays the data from the call I need. I have experience with HTML and have read through the CSS, Javascript, and XML guides on W3schools.com but don't know how to put together what I've learned to accomplish this end. Is there something in addition to what I've read that can help me understand how to accomplish this goal? Or suggestions on the code itself?

Help would greatly be appreciated as this tool will be used (if I can get it to work) by my whole department here at eBay Customer Support.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to get registered with the eBay's developer program from its [official website](https://www.x.com/developers/ebay). You can get more support and documentation from there. It would be more helpful if you told us which language you are working with. As the API calls need to be made any specific language and not just HTML/Javascript. [Here](https://www.x.com/ebay-trading-api-code-sample-perl) is a sample code that i came across on the official developer site of eBay. It is written in Perl but you can get the idea of the flow of programming and then can covert it in any language of your choice.

I hope it helps or at least gets you started in the right direction.